# Maven error while run an command through command line

Tags: java, apache, maven, eclipse-plugin

I tried to run mvn install command,but I am getting below error.

```
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.6 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection reset
```

Comment: Looks like a Proxy issue

Comment: the error explains what is not working